# Does qt have a watch variable debugging function

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I try to observe when a member of a class get changed in QTCreator 5.2 but I do not find any relevant function like "watch variable" in Eclipse.

Does anyone know weather there's any alternative way to watch a variable's value changes?

Comment: Do you mean in the [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator) IDE?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes. QtCreator 5.2, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **data breakpoints** for this. You need:

1. Right-click in the Breakpoints view to open the context menu, and select Add Breakpoint.
2. In the Breakpoint type field, select Break on data access at fixed address.
3. In the Address field, specify the address of the memory block.
4. Select OK.

If the address is displayed in the Locals and Expressions view, you can select Add Data Breakpoint at Object's Address in the context menu to set the data breakpoint.

You can read more here [Qt Documentation: Interacting with the Debugger](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html)

Comment: And how do I find the address?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just hover at debug time and see the values. Check your preference setting at

Tools > Options > Debugger > General > “Use tooltips in main editor while debugging”

Comment: sorry for the confusion of my wording. But I am just wondering is there anyway to see during the execution of the program, the member variable's value got changed, the program stops.

Comment: I am looking for the same, i.e. a breakpoints that hits when a variable changes. I noticed that you can right click on a variable in the debug tree view and chose "Add data breakpoint". However it seems that it will hit on every access, not only modification. So that did not help me either.